# Alias Class Function to Shorter Name - Maintain Auto-Complete/JSDoc

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, jsdoc

I have several classes which are grouped in namespaces, generally two or three layers, like `A.B.C`. I'd like to store these in a single value which I can then use (such as just `C`).

Obviously, to do this in JavaScript is pretty simple.

```
var C = A.B.C;
var c = new C();
c instanceof A.B.C; // true
```

The problem I've run in to is that the Auto-completion in PhpStorm 7 completely loses track of what c is, and also can't figure out what parameters C takes. PhpStorm generally implements Google Closure and JSDoc, so I'm not sure if it is a shortcoming with those or PhpStorm, or if there is some obvious tag I'm just missing.

I've tried:

```
@type {A.B.C}
@borrows A.B.C as C
@borrows {A.B.C} as {C}
@returns {A.B.C}
@type {function(new:A.B.C)}
```

And more and none of those worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: may be, @alias (http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html) will do the thing?

Comment: I gave that a try as well but I couldn't get it to generate the results I was looking for.